# How to check window is open via openGL or Glut

Tags: opengl, glut, glu

I have seen a method in SFML called [isOpen](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/5d7843c58a850b4941d7d9794d6fede2bbc02833/src/SFML/Window/Window.cpp#L169) which checks if the window is open.

Is there any similar equivalent in openGL or GLUT which checks if the window is open?

Comment: @Rabbid76, How can I check if a particular window id does exist?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I wonder how SFML is carrying it out.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I went to SFML from GLUT and now I am trying to translate my code back to GLUT as SFML renders objects with mistake in their distance related priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL render to a framebuffer attached to an OpenGL rendering context. The rendering context may have been created from a window connecting the (default) framebuffer to the window, but this is out of scope for the OpenGL spec.

As for GLUT you can use `glutSetWindow` to set the window id you want to check whether or not it exist, and then do `glutGetWindow`. If it returns the window id previously set the window exist. If not, `glutSetWindow` obviously failed because the window does not exist.

Whether or not this is true [seems implementation dependent](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node98.html#SECTION000153000000000000000), but I doubt anyone would be stupid enough to not implement error handling in such a trivial case.

Comment: does using `glutSetWindow` have overhead? Also is there a guarantee that always window id >0 for an existing window ?

Comment: @ar2015 Yes, though I have not measured how much as none of my applications have performance issues in the sections where it appears. And yes to you second question, ["The range of allocated identifiers starts at one"](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node16.html#SECTION00051000000000000000)